# How to send multiple images with data in retrofit android?

Tags: android, kotlin, postman, retrofit2, multipartform-data

[image: Here is the postman equivalent]

I want to send same data via android. I am using retrofit2. I have tried various other codes
like

```
 @Multipart
    @POST(POST_OTHER)
    suspend fun postOthers(
        @Part file: RequestBody
    ): Response<StringResponse>
```

It give errors like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Part annotation must supply a name or use MultipartBody.Part parameter type.
```

I dont know how to properly send the data in correct format. All the help would be appreciated.

- - EDIT * *
- I achieved my result but using ok http

```
 val builder: MultipartBody.Builder = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            builder.addFormDataPart("user_id", "38")
            builder.addFormDataPart("name", "Yippee")
            builder.addFormDataPart("feature", "4")
            builder.addFormDataPart("title", "4")
            builder.addFormDataPart("description", "4")
            builder.addFormDataPart("price", "40.12")
            builder.addFormDataPart("cat", "hmmmm")

            for ((i, item) in finalImageList.withIndex()) {
                val file = filePath.createFileFromUri(item.uri!!)
                builder.addFormDataPart(
                    "file[$i]",
                    file?.name,
                    file!!.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaType())
                )
            }

            val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                .url(Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.POST_OTHER)
                .post(builder.build())
                .build()
            val response: Response = OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()
            if (response.isSuccessful && response.body != null) {
                " success ${request.body}".printLog()
            } else "Some error".printLog()
```

It would be helpful if i can get an equivalent retrofit code

Answer (score 0):

Use annotation @Body

```
@POST(POST_OTHER)
suspend fun postOthers(@Body body: RequestBody): Response<StringResponse>
```

in request fun create --> MultipartBody.Builder()

```
val multipart = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

multipart.addFormDataPart(
name = "file",
   filename = file1.name,
   body = file1.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaType())
)

multipart.addFormDataPart(
   name = "file",
   filename = file2.name,
   body = file2.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaType())
)

multipart.addFormDataPart(
   name = "file",
   filename = file3.name,
   body = file3.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaType())
)
```

...

where "file1, file2 file3" is your image (Uri) which was converted to a File.

and add to multipart other params (title, description, price, cat...)

```
multipart.addFormDataPart("title", title)
multipart.addFormDataPart("description", description)
```

....

```
private fun sendRequest() {
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      postOthers(multipart.build())
   }
}
```

Comment: this solution did not work